# Enable syntax highlighting for PowerShell 7 in vscode?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm trying out PowerShell 7 and swapped my terminal over from PS6. However, upon doing so it killed syntax highlighting and I haven't been able to figure out how to get it back. Does PS7 have syntax highlighting? If so, has anyone gotten it working?

Comment: Do you have the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) installed? That should give you syntax highlighting up to the latest stable release at least

Comment: I do - it was working fine pre-7. Does it work for you on 7? 7 is technically still in RC so maybe that has something to do with it

Comment: Latest stable release is [7.0.3](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v7.0.3) - the vscode extension's integrated console seems to default to the latest installed version (don't quote me on that), so I simply installed 7.0.3 on my machine, and now the extension works with 7.0.3 (_without_ me having changed the terminal configuration)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you! I made the mistake of following Microsoft's official documentation which pointed to an old version. I didn't consider the official install doc would be out of date hahaha. With the current version it works fine. If you want to throw that into an answer I'll mark it.

Comment: Went back to make sure I wasn't insane. This is the link in the docs: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases. Oddly enough the RC is the newest listed unless you go look at the tags .

Comment: Yeah, the GitHub "releases" page doesn't have the best overview or filtering options by default, easiest way is to click the `Tags` selector at the top and then pick the latest version _not_ postfixed with `rc` or `preview` (or browse `.../releases/latest` explicitly)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen if you throw that in an answer I'll mark it